# Trying to launch script/console using Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

Using Rails 3. In my project directory am trying to launch rails script/console by using "rails console" command line & get this in return.
    `Loading test environment (Rails 3.2.1)`
    `irb(main):001:0>`

Comment: Is the problem that the test environment is loading instead of development?

Comment: Am not sure. Am a noob here. Basically when I start a server for my app, the command prompt never returns. I want to pop open another console that I can run my commands thru. I should be able to do it using `rails console` but when I run it I get `Loading test environment (Rails 3.2.1) irb(main):001:0>` with no return of command prompt.

Comment: That irb thing there is the rails console (try typing some ruby in there). You won't get your platform's command prompt back until you run exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be confused about the `rails` commands.

`rails server` (or `script/server` when using Rails 2.x) is used to start a web server for local development (this by default is Webrick running on `0.0.0.0:3000`). This process runs in the foreground and does not allow for interaction. It will log output to STDOUT.

`rails console` (or `script/console` when using Rails 2.x) is used to start the interactive ruby shell (irb) with your Rails app and environment (`development` by default, `test` in your case) loaded. This is an interactive shell meaning that you can type ruby code in here and it will be executed when you hit the return key or when it encounters the end of a block. Try this out

```
a = ["b", "a", "r","t"]
a.reverse
```

Will return

```
=> ["t", "r", "a", "b"]
```

Since this also loads your Rails application, you have access to the classes defined in your application. For example, if you have a `Person` model defined, you can instantiate a new instance by typing the following into irb

```
Person.new
```

To leave the irb, you can type `exit` to return to your operating system's shell. I hope this helps to clear up some of the confusion.

Comment: Thanks Bart and everyone else. I just started but after working my way through tutorials I finally get it. Well explanation as well. Thanks